# Installing Intel SDK for OpenCL Application Setup and got an error below

Tags: opencl

My laptop hardware information is as follows:

OS: Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3540M CPU @ 3.00 GHz
RAM: 16,0 GB
Graphics: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000

When I try to install Intel SDK for OpenCL Application 2014 setup, it gives the following error.
Would you please help me out in this problem ?

Thanks in advance..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from Dithermaster is correct. I would add comment to that answer, but currently I cannot due to reputation score limitation. Your processor is 3rd Generation Intel® Core™ Processors with Intel® HD Graphics 4000, so you need to install corresponding driver. The latest one is [15.33.30.64.3958](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=24329&lang=eng&ProdId=3712). The only concern is that sometimes laptop manufacturers provide their own customized version of the Gfx driver and prohibit installation of the generic one. In this case you might try to install OpenCL runtime for [CPU](http://registrationcenter.intel.com/irc_nas/4180/opencl_runtime_14.2_x64_setup.msi) only.

Comment: Appreciate for the explanations to both you guys. I installed opencl_runtime_setup and then installed intel_sdk respectively.It didn't complain, and added opencl template on visual studio. I believe this solution help will many developers. Kindest Regards...

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to follow the link and install a newer driver. The SDK doesn't include the latest driver anymore; they are installed separately. The SDK is the headers and whatnot that you need for development; the driver provides the runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I followed the link but it listed the followings:                                                        Contents
•Intel® SDK for OpenCL™ Applications (that I try to install)
•OpenCL driver for Intel® Iris™ and HD Graphics for Windows (64-bit and 32-bit)
•OpenCL™ Runtime 14.2 for Intel® CPU and Intel® Xeon Phi™ coprocessors for Linux* (64-bit)
•OpenCL™ Runtime 14.2 for Intel® CPU and Intel® Xeon Phi™ coprocessors for Windows* (64-bit)
•OpenCL™ Runtime 14.2 for Intel® Core Procs for Windows* (32-bit). The rest doesn't meet with laptop's hardware spec. Any suggestion ?