# Intel SDK for OpenCL Installation

Tags: opencl, gpu, intel

My question is related to the following question:

[Installing Intel SDK for OpenCL Application Setup and got an error below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975906/installing-intel-sdk-for-opencl-application-setup-and-got-an-error-below)

When I try to install the Intel SDK for OpenCL it tells me that the OpenCL driver is missing or out of date.

The problem I also have is that I cannot even install the OpenCL™ Runtime for Intel® Core.
This is the message I get:

[image]

When I try to uninstall the Intel HD graphics driver it gets installed back.
I have tried to disconnect from the internet, uninstall the driver, restart and try to install the OpenCL Runtime, but it gives me the same message.

---

My laptop has:

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU
- Intel(R) HD Graphics

Comment: What CPU model do you have?

Comment: The SDK install did that? I know the CPU driver install does that, but I guess the SDK must include that somehow if you are seeing it. Technically you can uninstall your GPU driver, install the SDK and/or CPU driver, then re-install your GPU driver, but that's a lot of work for an SDK which is really just some header files and a static lib wrapper for the OpenCL.dll that's already installed. You could install the AMD or NVIDIA SDK and get the same things.

Comment: CPU-only Runtime package "OpenCL Runtime for Intel Core and Intel Xeon Processors" as it is named on the website gave me that message. I went through the process you describe with uninstalling the driver, then installing the SDK (the CPU driver gave me the same message). But, the OpenCL driver remained uninstalled. And so, my OpenCL programs return zeros.
@AndrewSavonichev my CPU is Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU  M430 2.27GHz. Maybe my laptop cannot even run OpenCL.

Comment: Please ask this question at Intel's OpenCL Forum: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/OpenCL. Also, if you want to avoid reinstallation of the driver you need to check the "Delete the driver software for this device" box

Comment: @RobertIoffe, I have tried with and without "Delete the driver software for this device". No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Intel software is a horrible mess, bigger than its hardware mess (and their help is so useful as an hernia), in my experience:

OpenCL and Cuda SDKs are hardware dependent and driver specific, so you should install the included driver, in the case it doesn't work, try updating your computer bios and try again.

I have to use Intel OpenCL not by my own choice, the SDK keeps uninstalling itself silently and sometimes makes the computer lag. and I have an i7 7thGen with Intel HD-630.